# How to get log by using logog in DLL API's in C++

Tags: c++, error-logging

How to write log inside DLL API?

In my program I am using two threads with one main thread. I am initializing:

```
LOGOG_INITIALIZE();

logog::LogFile errFile("log.txt");
```

Into my main thread and using `INFO`, `ERR` in main thread other two threads. My main thread is using C++ DLL API's. I am perfectly getting log from main thread and two other running thread but my problem is I am not able to get log from DLL API's flow. How to get log by using logog in DLL API's. I would like to clear here if I am using `INFO` in DLL API. it is crashing but if I do `LOGOG_INITIALIZE();` inside DLL API, `INFO` executes but does not log anything.

Answer (score 0):

If i get it correct, your situation is as follows: You have, for example, one application (EXE) which uses a shared library (DLL). From both, the EXE and the DLL, you want to be able to log.

Last time i checked out the [logog](http://johnwbyrd.github.com/logog/) library i run in problems with the situation described above. Maybe now it is corrected?

Under windows (only!), the [logog](http://johnwbyrd.github.com/logog/) library doesn't export any symbols - it is simply not ready to be used as DLL. This forces you to build and use [logog](http://johnwbyrd.github.com/logog/) as static library - which leads to problems with static variables inside the [logog](http://johnwbyrd.github.com/logog/) library which should exist only once, but in reality are existing as many times as the static library was linked to a module (EXE or DLL).

The solution would be to build and use the [logog](http://johnwbyrd.github.com/logog/) library as DLL.

Maybe this covers your problem and you may take the effort to export the symbols of the [logog](http://johnwbyrd.github.com/logog/) library. Or you could get in contact with the library writer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But not able to understand exactly how using as dll istead of lib will resolve the issue.

Comment: @user1648040: Maybe you should provide some sample code to illustrate/reproduce your problem exactly.